# Does AVSpeechSynthesizer work on xcode 4.6.2?

Tags: ios

I am making a language translation app on xcode 4.6.2. When I used AVSpeechSynthesizer to declare its delegate in .h file it gave an error : "protocol declaration not found for AVSpeechSynthesizerDelegate" though I had imported AVFoundation Framework. Do I need any file or is it because this feature is only supported by ios 7 and above?

So do I need to install iOS 5? I do not have a macbook, I have installed iATKOS ML2 on HP i5 (in case the problem relates to drivers for sound). Xcode works fine and so does media files.

Comment: You need `Xcode 5` since it is `iOS 7` object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, It is introduced in Xcode 5.0 or iOS 7.0.
So, thats why you are getting this error. So please update your Xcode and then use it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply :) so do I need to download the whole dmg file or is there a shorter way of updating it?